# Apache HTTPd FollowSymLinks path permission

Tags: configuration, httpd, documentroot

I'm configuring my development environment with a basic Apache HTTPd configuration.

But, to avoid a often problem, I want to map my test URL to my development folder.

I'm using Ubuntu.

My development path is located under the following example path:

```
/home/myusername/myworkspace/hptargetpath/src/pages
```

Considering the following symbolic link mapping:

```
#ls -l /opt/share/www/mydevelopmentrootpath:
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 77 2011-02-13 18:53 /opt/share/www/mydevelopmentrootpath -> /home/myusername/myworkspace/hptargetpath/src/pages
```

With this folder mapping, I configured Apache HTTPd with the following configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
        ServerName local.server.com
        ServerAdmin some@test.com
        DirectoryIndex index.html

        DocumentRoot /opt/share/www/mydevelopmentrootpath

        <Directory /opt/share/www/mydevelopmentrootpath/ >
                Options +Indexes
                Options +FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

But, I'm receiving a 403 Forbidden error when I want to access index.html under the address http://local.server.com/index.html.

```
403 Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /index.html on this server.
```

On httpd debug log, I checked the following message:

```
[Sun Feb 13 19:34:47 2011] [error] [client 127.0.1.1] Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /opt/share/www/mydevelopmentrootpath
```

I'm thinking that this problem is been generated by some path permission. It's not a direct permission to directory, but some intermediate directory in the path.

There's a directive on httpd core Options:

```
SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
The server will only follow symbolic links for which the target file or directory is owned by the same user id as the link.
```

But, I tested it without effects.

Somebody may help me? I think that it's a trivial configuration on development environment.

Best regards,

And Past

Answer (score 1):

apache needs 'execute' right for all parent directories of `/home/myusername/myworkspace/hptargetpath/src/pages` in order to follow the symlink. you can grant that right with

```
chmod o+x /home
chmod o+x /home/myusername
chmod o+x /home/myusername/myworkspace
chmod o+x /home/myusername/myworkspace/hptargetpath
chmod o+x /home/myusername/myworkspace/hptargetpath/src
chmod o+x /home/myusername/myworkspace/hptargetpath/src/pages
```

in most cases, that helps.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem yesterday. we could solve it be changing the symlink ownership down to the userlevel:

```
chown -h <user>.<group> <symlink>
```

apache recognizes the symlink ownership and raises errors if symlink ownership does not fit. in the error_log you can only read "Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible". Don't forget the -h option since you change the target ownership otherwise.